# Jupyter Notebook external authentication for trino connection

Tags: authentication, jupyter-notebook, trino

I am connecting to a starburst server to perform a SQL query through the library "trino" in Python. I am doing this in a jupyter notebook and everytime I run a query I have to manually click on the URL that appears to open the a new tab in my browser to authenticate. A couple of months ago this tab was opened automatically by the notebook(without the necessity of me clicking on the URL) but then I updated something and now I always have to click on the URL to authenticate. Do you know how to let the jupyter notebook authenticate automatically?

[image]